# Oracle check depending on multiple columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm having a problem where I can't really find a solution for because it is very specific and I'm hoping you could help me:

```
    CREATE TABLE books (
  passagierid NUMBER NOT NULL CONSTRAINT fk_bucht_passagier REFERENCES passagier, --FK
  flightnr VARCHAR2(8) NOT NULL,
  dep_date DATE NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT fk_bucht_flug FOREIGN KEY (flightnr, dep_date) REFERENCES flug, --FK
  CONSTRAINT pk_bucht PRIMARY KEY (passagierid, flightnr, dep_date), --PK
  bookingnr NUMBER NOT NULL CONSTRAINT ak_bookingnr UNIQUE,
  [...]
  seatnr VARCHAR2(5) NOT NULL,
  [...]

  -- something like that:
  CONSTRAINT chk_sitzpl_gleiche_buchung CHECK((seatnr,bookingnr,dep_date,flightnr) 
      NOT IN (SELECT seatnr,bookingnr,dep_date,flightnr FROM books))
  );
```

So inputs like these, where the same flight number, date and seat have to have the same booking number should be checked:

```
-- insert into books values (...,'PW2345','19.11.2013 15:02:00',1,...,'12c',...)
-- insert into books values (...,'PW2345','19.11.2013 15:02:00',2,...,'12c',...) not ok
```

Comment: This should be a `UNIQUE` constraint.

Comment: But I think the constraint should be on `UNIQUE(seatnr,dep_date,flightnr)`. Do not include `bookingnr` as this has already a UNIQUE constraint on it.

Comment: And I guess that you don't want 2 customers on the same flight-number, same day and same seat.

Comment: but its the combination of all 4 that has to be unique so doesnt it also have to be the four?

Comment: Your own example shows that the combination of the 3 columns has to be unique. The booking-numbers can be different (like it is, `1` and `2` in your example.)

Comment: no, i meant that the second example should not be accepted

Comment: That's what I mean, too. If the constraint is in the 4 columns, your second example will be accepted. Try it.

Comment: aah sry guess my brain isnt working anymore xD i get what you mean, corrected it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a unique constraint on those columns.

SYNTAX IS:

```
CREATE TABLE XYZ(
....,
....,
CONSTRAINT <constraint_name> UNIQUE(column-list separated by commas));
```

You can read more about it [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp)

Comment: Thank you soo much!! such a simple answer and ive already spent so much time looking for it, damn..^^ i guess i didnt realize that unique can be applied on multiple columns.
Anyways, thanks a lot, especially for such a fast answer!
Have a great sunday!